# How to dynamically generate columns in rdlc report according to the data in dataset?

Tags: c#, rdlc, subreport, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I would like to generate a report in which column name and value should be dynamic and no. The column also should be dynamic.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share with us what you have tried so far.

Comment: check this link pls:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898087/generate-columns-dynamically-in-rdlc

Comment: the link above suggest to use RDL instead of RDLC. But I have to do this in RDLC

Answer (score 0):

Your question is obscure. it seems below code worked for your purpose:

```
public Form1()
    {
        dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        reportButton.Text = "Generate Report";
        reportButton.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        reportButton.Click += new EventHandler(reportButton_Click);

        Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        Controls.Add(reportButton);
        Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        Text = "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Demo";
    }

    // Initializes the data source and populates the DataGridView control.
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateLists();
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tasks;
        AddColumns();
    }

    // Populates the employees and tasks lists. 
    private void PopulateLists()
    {
        employees.Add(new Employee("Harry"));
        employees.Add(new Employee("Sally"));
        employees.Add(new Employee("Roy"));
        employees.Add(new Employee("Pris"));
        tasks.Add(new Task(1, employees[1]));
        tasks.Add(new Task(2));
        tasks.Add(new Task(3, employees[2]));
        tasks.Add(new Task(4));
    }

    // Configures columns for the DataGridView control.
    private void AddColumns()
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn idColumn = 
            new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        idColumn.Name = "Task";
        idColumn.DataPropertyName = "Id";
        idColumn.ReadOnly = true;

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn assignedToColumn = 
            new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

        // Populate the combo box drop-down list with Employee objects. 
        foreach (Employee e in employees) assignedToColumn.Items.Add(e);

        // Add "unassigned" to the drop-down list and display it for 
        // empty AssignedTo values or when the user presses CTRL+0. 
        assignedToColumn.Items.Add("unassigned");
        assignedToColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "unassigned";

        assignedToColumn.Name = "Assigned To";
        assignedToColumn.DataPropertyName = "AssignedTo";
        assignedToColumn.AutoComplete = true;
        assignedToColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
        assignedToColumn.ValueMember = "Self";

        // Add a button column. 
        DataGridViewButtonColumn buttonColumn = 
            new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        buttonColumn.HeaderText = "";
        buttonColumn.Name = "Status Request";
        buttonColumn.Text = "Request Status";
        buttonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(idColumn);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(assignedToColumn);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(buttonColumn);

        // Add a CellClick handler to handle clicks in the button column.
        dataGridView1.CellClick +=
            new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellClick);
    }

    // Reports on task assignments. 
    private void reportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder report = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Task t in tasks)
        {
            String assignment = 
                t.AssignedTo == null ? 
                "unassigned" : "assigned to " + t.AssignedTo.Name;
            report.AppendFormat("Task {0} is {1}.", t.Id, assignment);
            report.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(report.ToString(), "Task Assignments");
    }

    // Calls the Employee.RequestStatus method.
    void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ignore clicks that are not on button cells. 
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex !=
            dataGridView1.Columns["Status Request"].Index) return;

        // Retrieve the task ID.
        Int32 taskID = (Int32)dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value;

        // Retrieve the Employee object from the "Assigned To" cell.
        Employee assignedTo = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
            .Cells["Assigned To"].Value as Employee;

        // Request status through the Employee object if present. 
        if (assignedTo != null)
        {
            assignedTo.RequestStatus(taskID);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format(
                "Task {0} is unassigned.", taskID), "Status Request");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No, I don't have datagridview. I just want to show data of one column as column name and data of another column as the value in row from dataset in which data of the column of which should be column name is dynamic,

Comment: This is code for a data grid in WinForms, not an RDLC report.